# What should we do with ast-golf?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags

The [ast-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ast-golf) tag is a winning criterion where the program with the least AST nodes wins. This seems like a subset of [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf), where the program with the least operations by some definition wins.

It has [one question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ast-golf), which  looks quite similar to a typical [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf) question:

> ### Scoring Heuristics
>
> The following rules are typically enough to calculate the score of your program:
>
> - Block statements are 1 points: if, for ... in ..., while, else, etc.
> - Standalone statements are 1 point: print in Python 2, break, pass, etc.
> - Variables are 2 points
> - ...

Also, the [original intent](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/403/new-code-golf-metric-atomic-code-golf) of the [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf) tag was to count a single token per statement / value / similar in a program, in an attempt to level the  playing field.

So, what should we do with [ast-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ast-golf)?

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10609/16766)

Comment: @DLosc [And a comment on that](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10609/abstract-syntax-tree-golfing#comment34895_10609)

Answer (score 14):

## Merge it into [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf)

> Do we really need [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [ast-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ast-golf) for this? Isn't this just a specific form of [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf)?
> - [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/100776/abstract-syntax-tree-golfing-fizzbuzz-python#comment245097_100776)
>
> The reason I did it this way is because the tag text for atomic-code-golf says "Atomic code golf is scored by the number of tokens of your program," and that's not the same as this, though perhaps only a pretty small amount.
> - [isaacg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/100776/abstract-syntax-tree-golfing-fizzbuzz-python#comment245262_100776)

Given that:

1. there have been no other [ast-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ast-golf) questions in over five years and
2. the OP admits that it's nearly the same as [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf) and
3. it's since been retagged *as* [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf)

I don't think the slight difference in scoring from regular [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf) makes enough of a difference to keep a separate tag. This challenge is a variant of [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf), the same way that a challenge that counts box-drawing characters as one byte is a variant of [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), or that [a challenge about xiangqi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/92897/16766) is a variant of [chess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess).

It might be worth updating the [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf) tag wiki to explicitly include this kind of variant.

Comment: And even if it was totally separate from [tag:atomic-code-golf], an OWC tag that applies to exactly one question is pointless to have anyway since [tag:code-challenge] exists